Springboot web -application Not showing data in console nor in H2 database
"Everthing is working fine but my input data is not showing in my console can anyone help me with it  you can check my index.html file in resource/templates folder and h2 console properties file
Github link
You can clone and run on your IDE

@GetMapping("/users")
public String getUser (Model model) {
    List<UserAccount> userlist= service.getAllUserAccounts();
    model.addAttribute("user", userlist);
    return "view-user";
}

In above code you are not sending user list to UI.
Use ModelAndView instead of Model .
you can use following code -
@GetMapping("/users")
public ModelAndView getUser (ModelAndView model) {
    List<UserAccount> userlist= service.getAllUserAccounts();
    model.addAttribute("user", userlist);
    model.setViewName("view-user");
    return model;
}


Thanks But not working

in your project view-user file not available in resources/templates

you mean index.html? its  present

Update index.html


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h3>User Account Form</h3>
        <p th:text ="${msg}" class="text-success"></p>
       
        <form th:action="@{/save-user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fullname</td>
                    <td> <input type="text" th:field="*{Fullname}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td> <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number</td>
                    <td> <input type="number" th:field="*{Phoneno}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>ssn</td>
                    <td> <input type="number" th:field="*{ssn}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Date of Birth</td>
                    <td> <input type="date" th:field="*{dob}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Gender</td>

                    <td> <input type="radio" th:field="*{Gender}" value="M" />Male</td>
                    <td> <input type="radio" th:field="*{Gender}" value="Fe" />Fe-male</td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>


            </table>
            <input type="submit" value=" Submit"  class="btn btn-primary" />

        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



And add annotation on "dob" in UserAccount.java
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") private LocalDate dob;
